# Every integer greater than 1 is divisible by at least one prime. Can anyone please express this in logical notation

Tags: number-theory

Every integer greater than 1 is divisible by at least one prime.

Can anyone please express this in logical notation

Comment: Do you have predicates for "is integer", "is greater than", "divides", "is prime" and a constant symbol for "1" available?

Answer (score 2):

We assume that variables range over the integers. We also assume that our language has equality, and binary function symbols $S$ and $P$ for addition and multiplication. We will be careless about parentheses.

We need to introduce certain abbreviations:

We write $x+y$ instead of $S(x,y)$ and $xy$ instead of $P(x,y)$.

$x^2$ abbreviates $xx$

$\text{IsOne}(x)$ abbreviates $(x^2=x) \land \exists t (\lnot (xt=x))$.

$\text{IsLess}(x,y)$ abbreviates $\lnot(x=y)\land \exists u_1\exists u_2\exists u_3\exists u_4(y=x+u_1^2+u_2^2+u_3^2+u_4^2)$.

$\text{Div}(x,y)$ abbreviates $\exists t (xt=y)$.

$\text{IsGreaterThanOne}(x)$ abbreviates $\exists t(\text{IsOne}(t)\land \text{IsLess}(t,x))$.

$\text{Prime}(x)$ abbreviates $\text{IsGreaterThanOne}(x)\land \forall u\forall v((uv=x)\implies (u^2=x^2)\lor (v^2=x^2))$.

Now comes our sentence.
$$\forall z(\text{IsGreaterThanOne}(z)\implies \exists w(\text{Prime}(w)\land \text{Div}(w,z))                                      ).$$

**Remark:** Some of the choices of abbreviation are a little peculiar, and could be changed. The above is almost certainly not what is intended that you do. For example, you are probaby allowed to use the constant symbols $0$ and $1$ freely, and the binary predicate symbol $\lt$. It should not be hard to turn the "hardine" approach taken above into a more relaxed approach that freely uses $0$, $1$, and $\lt$.

Answer (score 0):

$\forall n\ge 2 $ we may write $n=\prod_{j=1}^np_j^{\alpha_j}$ where each  $p_j$ is prime. And $\alpha_j\in \mathbb { N }_0$

Answer (score 0):

Using these auxiliary predicates respectively for *divisibility* and *primality*:

> $(m ~|~ n) \equiv \exists k: k* m = n$,
>
> $Prime(n) \equiv (n > 1) \land\forall m( m ~|~n \rightarrow (m = n ~\lor~ m = 1))$,

you can express it as follows:

> $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}(n > 1 \rightarrow \exists m \in \mathbb{N}: Prime(m) ~\land~ m ~|~ n)$